# gridview inside update panel is not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, updatepanel

i have some imagebuttons in GridView and when i clicked those image buttons whole page is refreshed. i just want to fire that image button event when i click to that imagebutton without reloading whole page. i have also used updatepanel.
i am facing this problem from two days now i need help i thing i cant do this.

this is my .aspx

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" ></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                 <Triggers>
                     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="updatebutton" EventName="Click" />
                 </Triggers>
                 <ContentTemplate>
                     <asp:ImageButton ID="updatebutton" runat="server" Visible="false" OnPreRender="ImageButton_PreRender" OnClick="ImageButton_Click" />
                     <asp:GridView ID="gvSeatLayout" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="755px" AllowPaging="True" 
                         OnRowDataBound="gvSeatLayout_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="gvSeatLayout_RowCreated"
                         PageSize="25" ShowHeader="False" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="5" BorderStyle="None"  >
                         <RowStyle CssClass="gvspace" />
                         <Columns>
                             <asp:TemplateField>
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                     <table>
                                         <tr><td>
                                             <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Enabled="false" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" CommandName="lbtnRowId" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RowId") %>'  Text='<%# RowName(Eval("RowName").ToString()) %>' runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                                         </td>
                                         </tr>
                                         <td></td></table>
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                                 <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField>
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" CssClass="ss" OnClick="ImageButton_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("L1") %>' CommandName="ib1"  runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# MyUrl(Eval("L1").ToString(),Eval("RowId").ToString()) %>' />
                                     <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="PopupControlExtender1" runat="server" popupcontrolid="Panel1"
                                         targetcontrolid="ImageButton1" dynamiccontextkey='<%# Eval("L1") %>' dynamiccontrolid="Panel1" 
                                         dynamicservicemethod="GetDynamicContent" position="Bottom">
                                     </asp:PopupControlExtender>
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                                 <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                             </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField>
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server"  CssClass="ss" OnClick="ImageButton_Click"    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("L3") %>' CommandName="ib3" ImageUrl='<%# MyUrl(Eval("L3").ToString(),Eval("RowId").ToString()) %>'/>
                                     <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="PopupControlExtender2" runat="server" popupcontrolid="Panel1"
                                         targetcontrolid="ImageButton3" dynamiccontextkey='<%# Eval("L3") %>' dynamiccontrolid="Panel1" 
                                         dynamicservicemethod="GetDynamicContent" position="Bottom">
                                     </asp:PopupControlExtender>
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                                 <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField>
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server"  CssClass="ss" OnClick="ImageButton_Click"    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("L4") %>' CommandName="ib4" ImageUrl='<%# MyUrl(Eval("L4").ToString(),Eval("RowId").ToString()) %>'/>
                                     <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="PopupControlExtender3" runat="server" popupcontrolid="Panel1"
                                         targetcontrolid="ImageButton4" dynamiccontextkey='<%# Eval("L4") %>' dynamiccontrolid="Panel1" 
                                         dynamicservicemethod="GetDynamicContent" position="Bottom">
                                     </asp:PopupControlExtender>
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                                 <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                             </asp:TemplateField>


                             <asp:TemplateField>
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton8" runat="server" CssClass="ss"  OnClick="ImageButton_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("U1") %>' CommandName="ib8"  ImageUrl='<%# MyUrl(Eval("U1").ToString(),Eval("RowId").ToString()) %>'/>
                                     <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="PopupControlExtender4" runat="server" popupcontrolid="Panel1"
                                         targetcontrolid="ImageButton8" dynamiccontextkey='<%# Eval("U1") %>' dynamiccontrolid="Panel1" 
                                         dynamicservicemethod="GetDynamicContent" position="Bottom">
                                     </asp:PopupControlExtender>
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                                 <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                             </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField>
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton10" runat="server" CssClass="ss" OnClick="ImageButton_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("U3") %>' CommandName="ib10"  ImageUrl='<%# MyUrl(Eval("U3").ToString(),Eval("RowId").ToString()) %>'/>
                                     <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="PopupControlExtender5" runat="server" popupcontrolid="Panel1"
                                         targetcontrolid="ImageButton10" dynamiccontextkey='<%# Eval("U3") %>' dynamiccontrolid="Panel1" 
                                         dynamicservicemethod="GetDynamicContent" position="Bottom">
                                     </asp:PopupControlExtender>
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                                 <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField>
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton11" runat="server" CssClass="ss" OnClick="ImageButton_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("U4") %>' CommandName="ib10" 
                                         ImageUrl='<%# MyUrl(Eval("U4").ToString(),Eval("RowId").ToString()) %>'/>
                                     <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="PopupControlExtender6" runat="server" popupcontrolid="Panel1"
                                         targetcontrolid="ImageButton11" dynamiccontextkey='<%# Eval("U4") %>' dynamiccontrolid="Panel1" 
                                         dynamicservicemethod="GetDynamicContent" position="Bottom">
                                     </asp:PopupControlExtender>
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                                 <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                             </asp:TemplateField>


                         </Columns>
                         <FooterStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                         <SelectedRowStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                         <EditRowStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                         <AlternatingRowStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                     </asp:GridView>
                 </ContentTemplate>
             </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change the update mode to "Always". At the moment, the Async method is tied with the "updatebutton".

Comment: but how can i do this?

Comment: @Syed Add `UpdateMode` Attribute to your `UpdatePanel` Control to `Always`

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the triggers tag after the content template end tag like this...
`...</ContentTemplate> <Triggers> <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="updatebutton" EventName="Click" /> </Triggers>`